# How to go to previous step in 10.04 server installation?

Tags: 10.04, installation, server, setup

I'm installing ubuntu server 10.04 in text mode. How to go to previous step to configure network?

Comment: at least 8.04 said on the screen how I could go back. Isn't there a command on the screen?

Comment: Nope. However I saw step selection once. It was after partitioning dialog which had 'back' button.

Comment: after a certain point there is no return. Why do you want to go back? is there a way to see on what step you are? (like 5/10)

Comment: Nevermind, I've formatted everything and started installation over. I was at step after package installation and just wanted to configure network.

Comment: then you should have done that after the installation was complete...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation will always tell you if you can go back with the command written somewhere.

But if you reach the point of no return and still wants to go back. Then there is no command. Either you start over with a fresh install or you try to fix what you wanted to change when the installation is complete.